# Can't convert integer to string

Tags: python

I'm slightly puzzled on this problem that I have with my Python program. It's a very simple program but it keeps coming up with a problem. Allow me to show you the code...

```
x=int(input('Enter number 1:'))
y=int(input('Enter number 2:'))
z=x+y
print('Adding your numbers together gives:'+z)
```

Now, this program, when I run it keeps on saying that "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly".

I just want it to run normally. 
Could anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at your `input` lines and spot the obvious difference...

Comment: @TomFenech That's not a good duplicate. The title is similar but the question is rather different.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I take your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is obvious because you can't concatenate `str` and `int`. Better approach: you can separate string and the rest of `print`'s arguments with commas:

```
>>> x, y = 51, 49
>>> z = x + y
>>> print('Adding your numbers together gives:', z)
Adding your numbers together gives: 100
>>> print('x is', x, 'and y is', y)
x is 51 and y is 49
```

`print` function will take care of the variable type automatically. The following also works fine:

```
>>> print('Adding your numbers together gives:'+str(z))
Adding your numbers together gives:100
>>> print('Adding your numbers together gives: {}'.format(z))
Adding your numbers together gives: 100
>>> print('Adding your numbers together gives: %d' % z)
Adding your numbers together gives: 100
```

Answer (score 3):

You should rewrite the last line as:

```
print('Adding your numbers together gives:%s' % z)
```

because you cannot use `+` sign to concatenate a `string` and an `int` in Python.

Answer (score 3):

Your error message is telling you exactly what is going on.

`z` is an `int` and you're trying to concatenate it with a string. Before concatenating it, you must first convert it to a string. You can do this using the `str()` function:

```
print('Adding your numbers together gives:' + str(z))
```